# How to create an Self Signed Certificate on Windows server 2012 r2 for application hosted on websphere

Tags: iis, certificate, websphere, single-sign-on, self-signed-certificate

I am trying to create a Self Signed Certificate on windows 2012 r2 for an application hosted on websphere.

My application is something like https://server1.xxx.co.yy:9434/app/screen/login

and it gives not secure error on address bar.

Please let me know how to resolve this .

Comment: That's expected, as for this URL you need a certificate who covers server1.xxx.co.yy in its common name or DNS names, and also let all clients/browsers trust the certificate manually. Tons of work but you should get some assistance from the network administrators if you work for a firm.

Answer (score 3):

Chrome return this error, if the certificate is not a trusted CA certificate. If you want to just ignore this error click on the advance and then click to proceed to unsafe.

[image]

[image]

or another way is create a self-signed certificate with the Common name as your site URL which is server1.xxx.co.yy.

for that run PowerShell as administrator and then execute below command:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName www.test.com -CertStoreLocation cert:Localmachine\My
```

after creating certificate move certificate to the trusted root folder follow below steps:

- Press the Windows button on your keyboard
- Type 'cert'
- Click on 'Manage Computer Certificates'
- Under Personal, click on the Certificates folder
- Find the certificate you created
- Right click on it and choose 'Copy'
- Then under Trusted Root Certification Authorities right click on the Certificates folder and choose 'Paste'

[image]

You could add the self-signed certificate to chrome ca store:

https://superuser.com/questions/1083766/how-do-i-deal-with-neterr-cert-authority-invalid-in-chrome